# How to tie a widget to the center on different screen sizes?

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

In my example, there are boards with numbers. The figures displayed correctly on the screen size of 400x600.

[image]

But if you change the screen size to 1200x600, the numbers creep away from each other over a long distance:

[image]

Here's how I do it (cleanscreen.kv):

```
#:kivy 1.9.1

<CustomButton@Button>
    text: root.button_text
    size_hint_y: None
    text_size: root.width - 150, root.height
    valign: "middle"
    height: 40


<CleanScreen>
    orientation: "vertical"

    FloatLayout:
        Image:
            size_hint: .52, .52
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .23, "y": .30}
            allow_stretch: True
            source: "6.png"
        Image:
            size_hint: .52, .52
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .43, "y": .30}
            allow_stretch: True
            source: "5.png"
        Image:
            size_hint: .25, .25
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .54, "y": .35}
            allow_stretch: True
            source: "dot.png"
        Image:
            size_hint: .52, .52
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .65, "y": .30}
            allow_stretch: True
            source: "8.png"
        Image:
            size_hint: .18, .18
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .80, "center_y": .75}
            allow_stretch: True
            source: "gb.png"

ScrollView:
    GridLayout:
        id: gridlayout_ID
        cols: 1
        size_hint_y: None
        padding: 10
        height: self.minimum_height
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
```

cleanscreen.py:

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import kivy
kivy.require("1.9.1")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

Config.set("graphics", "width", "400")
Config.set("graphics", "height", "600")


class CustomButton(Button):
    button_text = StringProperty("")


class CleanScreen(BoxLayout):
    Builder.load_file("cleanscreen.kv")

    def __init__(self, **kvargs):
        super(CleanScreen, self).__init__(**kvargs)
        self.create_custom_button(self.ids.gridlayout_ID)

    def create_custom_button(self, gridlayout_ID):
        for i in range(50):
            gridlayout_ID.add_widget(
                CustomButton(button_text="Button {}".format(i)))

if __name__ in ["__main__", "__android__"]:
    class Test(App):
        def build(self):
            return CleanScreen()


    Test().run()
```

How to tie numbers to the center, the distance between them has always been the same on different screen sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the numbers images in a `BoxLayout`, and place the `BoxLayout` itself in the middle:

```
FloatLayout:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        #padding: play with this for better padding
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .50, "y": .30}
        Image: #I'm first
        Image: #2nd
        Image: #3rd
        ...
```